# How to prevent normalization of symfony config

Tags: symfony, configuration

I have a map in my config, that I defined using scalarPrototype.

The keys are strings in format `number x number` eg. `12x43` or `17x27`
It works fine for most cases except when first number is zero eg. `0x588`
When that happens symfony reads it not as a string, but as a hex number and returns `1416` instead.

Is there a way to either tell symfony that the key is a string, or disable normalization to prevent the conversion?

Some code to show the use case:

```
        $treeBuilder->getRootNode()
            ->children()
                ->arrayNode('formats')
                    ->arrayPrototype()
                        ->arrayPrototype()
                            ->scalarPrototype()->end()
                        ->end()
                    ->end()
                ->end()
            ->end();
```

```
formats:
  image:
    avatar:
      100x100: "60%"
      800x800: "90%"
    picture:
      0x800: "watermark"
      0x100: "watermark 70%"
      100x0: "watermark 70%"
      200x200: "crop watermark 70%"
```

Comment: Quoting the key works, not sure if there is a way to force it for specific node trees.

Comment: I am using quoting as a workaround for now, but it does not seem right to have some quoted and some unquoted, neither does changing 200 lines of config just because of one special case. I already had one big refactor when I found out I cannot use "-" in the key name for the resource name (it was eg. "user-avatar" before).

Comment: the key can be a string or a number. 0x[something] *obviously* is a number in hex notation. So if you want 0x[something]  to be a string, you have to quote it. and now before you change the interpreter and make a `.yaml` file be interpreted differently depending on the interpreter and specific settings being used, I'd advise to just effing write correct yaml, ffs. sorry, for being rude, but it's really ridiculous, which reasons lead to a degenerating yaml standard and files that look like yaml but aren't.